# What is the best (efficient) way to get a hash or unique key for a set of properties and values in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, optimization

I want to generate a DOM element class name based on the statically defined styles it has (in my framework). Basically, let's say there are 10,000 virtual elements. Each virtual element has 10 "static" CSS style attributes, as well as 5-10 "dynamic" style attributes. By "static" I mean that it is hardcoded to a fixed, unchanging value, and by dynamic I mean the value could change by being bound to the value of some variable, for example.

Now, in terms of optimization/theory, static CSS style attributes don't need to be written onto the `style` object of a native (non-virtual) element, they can instead all be grouped and put under a CSS class. This way we can just give the element a class and the styles get automatically applied. But the dynamic CSS style attributes must be set directly on the element like `el.style[name] = value`.

So all we need to do to make this happen is take all the statically defined CSS attributes and generate a unique class name for it. One naive way to do that is just do this:

```js
let hashId = 1
const stylesCache = {}

console.log(generateHash({ color: 'red' }))
console.log(generateHash({ color: 'red' }))
console.log(generateHash({ color: 'blue', fontFamily: 'Arial' }))
console.log(generateHash({ color: 'blue' }))

function generateHash(staticStyleAttributes) {
  const array = []
  Object.keys(staticStyleAttributes).sort().forEach(name => {
    const value = staticStyleAttributes[name]
    array.push(`${name}=${value}`)
  })
  const string = array.join(';')
  const id = stylesCache[string] = stylesCache[string] || hashId++
  return `myClassName-${id}`
}
```

But I'm not sure this is the best use of the object as a hash table, because the strings of the style attributes can get potentially pretty long (over 500 characters). Is there any better way to accomplish this? Something more elegant perhaps? Or tricky yet efficient?

Is it possible to take the generated style `string`, and run a hash function of some sort over it that is both efficient and simple? So it gives unique values depending on input, and also is fast? It doesn't need to be secure.

Using a hash function, too, we wouldn't need to store potentially hundreds of long key strings in a hash table, it would just be computed on the fly. So we skimp a little on memory too.

Comment: A 500-character string is nothing. Also it still scales linearly with the size of the generated CSS rules, so there's nothing to worry about. But if you don't want to use a map (or object) and a counter, sure, just apply some string hash function to it.

Comment: @Bergi what about [collisions](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/8765/is-there-a-hash-function-which-has-no-collisions)? I don't ever want to run into collisions. For example, I pick MD5 but it looks like there is the potential for collisions. Can you recommend something that works? Ideally simple, fast, small code footprint, but doesn't have to be all that.

Comment: MD5 collisions are very unlikely. *Any* hash will always have collisions.